# Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined functionCannot find either column

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I am able to execute the function inside SSMS it returns the expected values

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.AccDocumentHeaders
WHERE TypeDocumentId = 1
    AND dbo.MiladiToShamsi(DocumentDate, 'Saal') = 1395
```

But on entity framework,  I get this error when trying to execute the:

```
var q= "SELECT *  
        FROM dbo.AccDocumentHeaders 
        WHERE TypeDocumentId=1 
           AND [dbo].MiladiToShamsi(DocumentDate,'Saal')=1395 ";

var result = _uow.AccDocumentHeaders.SqlQuery(q).ToList();
```

> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function Cannot
>   find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate
>   "dbo.MiladiToShamsi", or the name is ambiguous

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this function "MiladiToShamsi' exists in DB? or it is accessible using dbo schema? Please check

Comment: Yes, It's worked when I Run query in SSMS

Comment: Are you sure it worked in ssms? Is it a scalar or table valued function ? I believe this error will be raised you call a table valued function like a scalar function

Comment: Yes,  it's Scalar valued function.

Comment: Remove the dbo from the function and check. As from entity framework connection, you might connect with some other schema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are using SSMS, you're working under the local administrator account which has a default schema set to `dbo`. But if your EF's `connection string` uses another user, default schema for this user is different from dbo and because of that, you will get `Cannot find column "dbo" ...`  error.
So make sure you grant the execute permission on function to the user which you currently trying to execute or use the correct schema `MyUserXYZ.MiladiToShamsi()` and also you should create this function with this `MyUserXYZ` schema too.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Nasiri, It's Worked. How can I give permission to Entity framework user in Seed Method (When Function Created) ?

Comment: My connection string is :     <add name="DbContext" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=123456;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below-mentioned Query.

```
SELECT ADH.*  FROM [dbo].[AccDocumentHeaders] as ADH,[dbo].[MiladiToShamsi] as MTS WHERE ADH.TypeDocumentId=1 AND (MTS.DocumentDate,'Saal')=1395
```

Comment: thanks, it does not worked, An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','

Answer (score 0):

Another cause is the actual dbo.Function doesn't exists!

Sometimes when you script a database you may create it in the order of Tables, Functions, Procedures and hit this error when you try to create a Table that references a Function that doesn't yet exist.